# Python automation tests: ImportError: liblapack.so.3gf

Tags: python

I am trying to get one of my Python automation tests working but unfortunately I encounter this error:

```
ImportError: liblapack.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The machine specs are: Linux crazlulinuxuser 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have installed the correct packages and here is the output from the absolute path for lapack:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack$ ls -Faithsl
total 19M
1060118 120K drwxr-xr-x 148 root root 116K Apr 25 14:07 ../
1705054 4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Apr 25 14:05 ./
1714629  12M -rw-r--r--   1 root root  12M Sep 13  2017 liblapack.a
1725288    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   18 Sep 13  2017 liblapack.so -> liblapack.so.3.7.1
1706104    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   18 Sep 13  2017 liblapack.so.3 -> liblapack.so.3.7.1
```

I have the following entry in `.bashrc` file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/nest-python/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack
```

I did follow other Stackoverflow solutions to similar problems but wasn't successful in getting this working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some binary/library you are using is linked specifically to "liblapack.so.3gf", which doesn't seem to exist on your system. Perhaps try creating a symbolic link named "liblapack.so.3gf" to "liblapack.so.3.7.1" (or it may be wiser to link to one of the existing links: "liblapack.so" or "liblapack.so.3").

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3gf
```

**Edit:** Apparently [these are the packages](https://packages.debian.org/sid/liblapack.so.3gf) on Debian systems that provide liblapack.so.3gf. I'm guessing "liblapack3" is the one you want. Is that installed? Also, Is your Python environment 64-bit like the liblapack libraries that are installed? If not, you will need to install the 32-bit (i386) liblapack package.

Comment: Thanks @AntumDeluge it worked with this workaround for a while but now I face a similar error -- ImportError: libblas.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I did create a symbolic link: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3gf

I updated the ~/.bashrc with export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/nest-python/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas
But the issue persists. Any pointers? Plz let me know.